# changing entry to float

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *


pencere = Tk() #Pencereyi Oluşturyor

def Ekmek(event):
    print(0.6*x)          
#Here i am trying to calcute the carbohydrate for diabetes
#1 gram of bread is 0.6 carbohydrate and i am trying to calculate the gram user enters
def Patates(event):
    print(0.16666666666666666)

gramy = Label(text = "Yemeğin Gramını Girin:",fg = "green",bg = "black")
gram = Entry(fg = "green",bg = "black")
x = gram.get() 

#In this part i want to change the "x" to a 
#float value but it gives error.How can i fix it ?


ekmek = Button(text="Ekmek",fg="orange",bg = "black")
ekmek.bind("<Button-1>",Ekmek)
patates = Button(text="Patates",fg="orange",bg = "black")
patates.bind("<Button-1>",Patates)
makarna = Button(text="Makarna",fg="orange",bg = "black")
pilav = Button(text="Pilav",fg="orange",bg = "black")

gramy.grid(row=0,column=1)
gram.grid(row =0,column =2)
ekmek.grid(row =1,column = 0)
patates.grid(row =1,column = 1)
makarna.grid(row = 1,column = 2)
pilav.grid(row = 2,column = 0)



pencere.mainloop() #Pencerenin Çarpıya
```

Comment: Don't just say it gives errors, what error? First of all, I would recommend you relearning tkinter since you never give the user to write anything to the Entry. Bind it to a button or something

Comment: But the user is going to enter the gram so if the user says 230gram and said i want bread it is going to do (0.6*230) so user can chose nearly everything

Answer (score 0):

Your problem code is very problematic because 'x' will always be `""` (empty string) since you placed it directly under its creation not giving any time for the user to enter. And as you know, `""` can not be floated.

This is your problem code:

```
gram = Entry(fg = "green",bg = "black")
x = gram.get()
```

You should place gram.get here:

```
def Ekmek(event):
    x = gram.get()
    x=float(x.split('gram')[0])
    print(0.6*x)
```

This will retrieve x after the user pressed the button.

*Another method, is that you can use a StringVar.*

Comment: Why is using a `StringVar` better? It adds an extra object that has to be managed, but doesn't provide any extra value. If there's a reason you think it's better, your answer could be improved if you explain why.